# Why Nuget sometimes creates different reference tags in different .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I added same nuget package to several C# projects in the same solution. However references in .csproj files are different. For example:

```
 <Reference Include="Company.Core, Version=1.0.14779.104, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Company.Core.1.2.0\lib\net45\Company.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and

```
<Reference Include="Company.Core">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Company.Core.1.2.0\lib\net45\Company.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Sometimes it creates `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` or `<Private>true</Private>` tags sometimes it doesn't - without apparent reason. WTF? Sometimes it puts qualified assembly name with a version sometimes it's just assembly name. Is there any clear documentation on how nuget comes up with each particular reference and why?
This behavior seems to exist both in VS 2013 and VS 2015. I have ReSharper installed. Could it be related to the tools?

Comment: This might have to do with a reference being changed from a direct reference to a package reference, or some tool you have. We use internal NuGet packages extensively and I don't have this in any of my 60-some projects.

Comment: Only ReSharper installed. Could be an assembly reference "promoted" to package reference or difference between package references created via R# and VS package manager but that was just clean install to multiple projects via VS Package Manager. If there's no valid documented behavior for this then will keep an eye on tools